# Adiabatic expansion and phase transition paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, adiabatic

It is possible for a (real) gas to increase its temperature during adiabatic expansion and whether this happens it is strongly dependent on the intermolecular interactions of the gas. We can explain this as an interplay between the work done on the surroundings and the change in the intermolecular spacing as the gas expands.

The heating can be understood by looking on the following figure [intermolecular potential](https://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/matter-mol-force-pe.php). If the initial pressure $P_i$ is very high (small mean free path) then average intermolecular potential energy $V_i$ would be more positive than the final $V_f$ (larger mean free path, $P_f$ is lower) and the $\Delta V$ would be negative.

This means that the kinetic energy $K$ should increase and if that increase can compensate for the decrease in $K$ due to the work on the surroundings, the gas's temperature would go up.

What I can't understand is how the gas is allowed in the first place to be found in such a state $P_i$, where the intermolecular potential is positive. Why the gas doesn't turn into a liquid when it reaches the intermolecular seperation where $V$ is minimum, since the attractive forces are the reason for the gas $\rightarrow$ liquid transition? Or why if we increase the pressure of the gas it will become liquid irrespective of the fact the forces are now becoming more repulsive?

Based on my reasoning these two phenomena are mutually exclusive, which obviously is not the case. I feel that I am missing something that would help me understand how these phenomena can be reconciled.

[image: 2]

Comment: "It is possible for a (real) gas to **heat up** during adiabatic expansion..." (Emphasis added). What do you mean to "heat up"? By definition no heat is exchanged during an *adiabatic* expansion. You mean the temperature goes up?

Comment: @hft "Heat up" when used intransitively (i.e., without a direct object) is an idiomatic verbal phrase referring to a temperature increase. No heat transfer is required. The terminology is correct.

Comment: @hft Thanks for the correction, I edited it.

Comment: Above the critical temperature, a gas cannot be condensed no matter how much pressure you apply.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yeah, sure, but I think it's still a little confusing given the meaning of heat. I'm not opposed to idiom, but it just might be a sticking point for some people like me right at the beginning of the question. Am I a pedant? Maybe. But so are a lot of others on this here forum.

Comment: The part of the question I don't understand is the implication that gases should turn into liquids to reduce internal energy. If internal energy minimization were dominant, everything would tend toward well-ordered solids. Gases turn into liquids instead to reduce the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy), which incorporates an entropy term mediated by the temperature. Pair potentials as shown in the figure apply to a single phase and can't replicate phase-change behavior.

Comment: Since the question is about the molecular origins of a positive [Joule–Thompson coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect), I recommend reading McClure's "[The Joule-Thomson coefficient—a molecular interpretation](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1986124?journalCode=ajp)," *American Journal of Physics* (1971) and perhaps its references and the relevant works citing it. I think you'll find this article useful because it also refers to a pair potential (specifically, a simple square potential).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Gibbs free energy is $G = H-TS$. If we keep increasing pressure (temperature is cosntant), that is we move to higher $V$, what is the reason that we are still in gas phase? Of course it must be entropy, but I can't understand how increasing pressure increases the former, such that $μ_{l} < μ_{g}$. Thanks for the articles, I will check them out.

Comment: Pressurizing a material always [promotes a shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation) to the lower-volume phase because the chemical potential scales with the [activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity), corresponding [essentially to the vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugacity). Therefore, providing more room for the vapor is more strongly favored at higher pressures.